# Unable to connect Socket IO express SSL (http works fine)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

**The problem:**

I've setup express to run with SSL which is working perfectly fine. But for some reason, the client keeps outputting 404 errors trying to connect to Socket IO.

**Server side code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./fullchain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //...
});

httpsServer.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //...
});
```

**Client side code used to connect:**
`var socket = io()`

Error:

> XHRGET
> https://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NRf9_6U
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Been trying several solutions from similar questions here, but all resulting in the same problem. I suspect it might be the use of port 3000 here, but I'm not sure. When I simply use http instead, it immediately works perfectly fine.

PS: replaced actual domain with `localhost` here as not to advertise.